Laravel 10 Eloquent Query Builder whereAny gives Unknown column 'any' Error
In Laravel 10 with Livewire, I have a view that has a search function to search the model using a LIKE statement. Instead of using orWhere, I was trying to use orWhere. The issue I am running into is that doing so, I am now getting an error from MySQL saying Unknown Column 'any'. Below is the search code. I have read over the documentation here, and cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated!
public function searchResults(string $partial): void
    {
        $this->brandAddresses= BrandAddress::whereAny([
            'title',
            'building_number',
            'pre_direction',
            'street_name',
            'street_type',
            'post_direction',
            'city',
            'state',
            'zip',
            'po_box'
        ], 'LIKE', '%' . $partial . '%')->orderBy('title')->get();
    }

In the documentation, it shows the code as using DB::table()->whereAny(), instead of Model::whereAny(), so I tried it that was as well, and still the same results. I am using PHPStorm, and it is indicating that whereAny does not exist as a function.

Thank you to @lagbox, I have found the solutions. I needed to updated my Laravel from 10.41 to 10.48 as it is apparently a new function.

are you sure you are using Laravel 10? because otherwise you are calling a dynamic whereXXX where XXX would be the column you want the where for

Yes, Laravel 10.41 is the version installed per my package.json.

if you change BrandAddress::whereAny to BrandAddress::whereTest does it print Unknown Column 'test' ?

this method was only added in the last month

Just ran composer update and now it is working. Thank you!!

added in 10.47.0 btw ... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/CHANGELOG.md#v10470---2024-03-05
